# Why can std::ref be used to use member functions as callable types?

Tags: c++, c++11

Please consider the following template function, that takes a callable, evaluates it, and returns the result (just for illustrative purposes):

```
template<typename F, typename... A>
auto evaluate(F&& f, A&&... args) -> decltype(f(std::forward<A>(args)...))
{
  return f(args...);
}
```

This works for free-standing functions, but it breaks when passing member functions as follows for example, where `foo` is an instance of `Foo`:

```
evaluate(&Foo::bar, foo, ...);
```

It complains about not being able to call the member function:

```
error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘f (...)’, 
e.g. ‘(... ->* f) (...)’ auto evaluate(F&& f, A&&... args) -> decltype(f(std::forward<A>(args)...))
```

Wrapping `f` in `std::ref` does allow passing member functions:

```
template<typename F, typename... A>
auto evaluate(F&& f, A&&... args) -> decltype(std::ref(f)(std::forward<A>(args)...))
...
```

Why does this work?

Comment: because the standard library is awesome

Comment: link to documentation here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator()

Comment: @RichardHodges What will be the `this` pointer passed to member function here?

Comment: @songyuanyao answer supplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality of making a reference_wrapper callable if the wrapped object is callable is fundamental to the ability to pass references to function objects into standard algorithms and the like.

here we create a tuple of references to function object:

```
int main()
{
    struct A {
        void operator()() const {
            std::cout << "A\n";
        }
    };

    struct B {
        void operator()() const {
            std::cout << "B\n";
        }
    };

    A a;
    B b;

    auto ab = std::tie(a, b);

    std::get<0>(ab)();
    std::get<1>(ab)();
}
```

And here we pass a reference to a stateful function object into a standard algorithm:

```
struct EqualAndCount
{
    EqualAndCount(char sought) : sought_(sought) {}

    template<class R>
    bool operator()(R const& r)
    {
        counter_++;
        return sought_ == r;
    }
    std::size_t counter_ = 0;
    char sought_;
};

int main()
{
    EqualAndCount eq('j');
    auto s = std::string("abcdefghijklmnop");
    auto i = std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), std::ref(eq));

    std::cout << "searched " << eq.counter_ << " chars";
    if (i == s.end())
        std::cout << " and did not find it\n";
    else
        std::cout << " and found it\n";
}
```

expected output:

```
searched 10 chars and found it
```

> Why does this work?

Because `std::reference_wrapper::operator()` is written in terms of the mythical `INVOKE` (up to c++14) and in terms of `std::invoke` (c++17).

documentation here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke